# AngularJS an issue with updating a DOM element containing an ng-click directive

Tags: html, angularjs, dom, angularjs-ng-click, angular-ng-if

I have been working on my 1st Angular website for nearly 2 weeks now, and have been trying to figure out the best way swap between 'Publish and Un-Publish' buttons on a list I generate with ng-repeat. I was about to ask how to solve this when it dawned on me. I decided to post the question and the solution I used in case some other newbie is struggling with a similar issue.
I had this:

```html
<div class="pull-right">
  <span id="publishButton{{ book.id }}" data-ng-if="book.published == '0'">
    <button class="btn btn-warning btn-sml" data-ng-click="publishBook(1, book.id)">Publish</button>
  </span>
  <span id="unpublishButton{{ book.id }}" data-ng-if="book.published == '1'">
    <button class="btn btn-warning btn-sml" data-ng-click="publishBook(0, book.id)">Un-Publish</button>
  </span>
</div>
```

After the 'Publisher method' finished I have tried various methods to replace the whole 'button's HTML (basically swap the context around). That worked patially except that that the 'ng-click' would not fire after the DOM change. I was about to plead for help, when I realised I should just reference the ng-if against a value I could manipulate after the publisher-method finishes.
Now I have this:

```html
<div class="pull-right">
 <span data-ng-if="bookArray[book.id] == 0">
  <button class="btn btn-warning btn-sml" data-ng-click="publishBook(1, book.id)">Publish</button>
 </span>
 <span data-ng-if="bookArray[book.id] == 1">
  <button class="btn btn-warning btn-sml" data-ng-click="publishBook(0, book.id)">Un-Publish</button>
 </span>
</div>
```

I created an Array booksArray within the scope, and before I load the List data into its array to be iterated I populate the reference array using angular.forEach like so:

```html
$scope.bookArray  = []; // this is the reference array
var outerArr      = data.records; // this is passed from my centralised 'backend function'
angular.forEach(outerArr, function(value, key) {
  this[value.id] = value.published;
}, $scope.bookArray);
```

When the 'Publisher method' finishes I now do this to complete the process:

```html
// item is now published - I update the visible 'published value' column in the data list
$scope.bookArray[bookID] = 1;
var elm = angular.element(document.querySelector('#publishValue'+bookID));
elm.html('1');
$scope.bookID = ''; // I store a reference to the item being published/unpublished - it gets cleared here
// the process values are reveresed for an unpublised item
```

Now the 'buttons' never leave the DOM and can be clicked and re-clicked after use. Problem solved!
If anyone has a better solution I'm all ears. 
I'm enjoying this new learning curve after 15yrs with PHP. My next challenge is a better understanding of the $watch processes and solving a $rootScope infdig error that occurs only on the initial redirection the default 'list' page when where it then displays the login form.

Comment: You should not post question with answer. And for sure this 'document.querySelector('#publishValue'+bookID)' is not angular.

Comment: Check codereview site, it would definitely be a better fit there

Comment: Yes, I probably broke protocol, but its due to the fact I have been searching here for over w  eek trying to solve this dilemma and just wanted to make it easier for someone with a similar issue.

Comment: Also, the 'document.querySelector()' was part of my attempts to get the DOM to recognise the updated HTML, none of which made any difference anyway. The process of replacing the 'button's worked with with a variety of methods including using just the 'angular.element() part, straight JS and even trying with jQuery, but I want to be able to use as little jQuery as possible. Nothing I tried would enable the 'button' after I replaced it. I would normally use jQuery.on() after an AJAX call, but my understanding is that it best to try and use native Angular techniques.